# Supply different JVM options to different runnable in Apache Twill

Tags: hadoop-yarn, apache-twill

In a Twill application lets say I have two types of runnables. One runnable has a 3GB container size and a different runnable has a 6GB container size. Now I want to set different -Xms option for these two runnable types. How do I supply different JVM options to different runnable types?

All I can find is this [setJVMOptions](http://twill.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/twill/yarn/YarnTwillRunnerService.html#setJVMOptions(java.lang.String)) function but it supplies the JVM options to all the runnables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This not possible in versions `0.11.0` and earlier.  This is fixed in trunk and will be in version `0.12.0`.  See ticket [TWILL-241](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TWILL-241) for details.